# Determining the CPU time required by C code using gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, profiling

I am using the gcc compiler for compiling C programs. How can I measure the exact CPU time required by a certain portion of C code or by a particular statement for its execution?

Comment: google "gcc time code" [result](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/464044-gcc-time-h-problem)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644730/c-measuring-computing-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a crude counter (~20ms resolution) is acceptable, this is my standard hacro:

```
#include <ctime>
#define CLOCK_TICK(acc, ctr)  ctr = std::clock()
#define CLOCK_TOCK(acc, ctr)  acc += (std::clock() - ctr)
#define CLOCK_RESET(acc) acc = 0
#define CLOCK_REPORT(acc) (1000. * double(acc) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))

static std::clock_t tacc, tctr;
```

Usage:

```
CLOCK_TICK(tacc, tctr);
do_something_critical();
CLOCK_TOCK(tacc, tctr);

std::cout << "This took " << CLOCK_REPORT(tacc) << "ms.\n";
```

In C++11 you can use `<chrono>` features to get higher-resolution clocks.

Comment: Trouble is, this will give you “wall” time; it’s likely the OP wants CPU time.  That will require interfacing with GCC’s profiling system.

Comment: @jcsalomon: Right, I see. On Linux you can try `getrusage()`, which provides the break-down that you get from the `time` command.

Comment: @jcsalomon: On some systems (e.g., MS VC++) `clock` returns wall time, but when properly implemented: "The clock function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the **processor
time** used by the program [...]" (§7.23.2.1/3, emphasis added).

Answer (score 1):

You want an execution profile of your application.  You’ll need to pass the `-pg` option to GCC when compiling & linking, then run the program through gprof.  See [this section](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_80.html) in Brian J. Gough’s *An Introduction to GCC* for a short overview of the process.