# How to interprete gprof output

Tags: c++, gprof

I just profiled my program with gprof and got this:

```
100.01      0.01     0.01    23118     0.43     0.43  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator=(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)
```

Which confuses me, as it says that it is using 100.01% of the time using the = operator. Am i right guessing that this means it is just copying data all along and is there a limit of how much memory a program is allowed to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you profiled too short a run to get any useful data.

The way `gprof` works is that it periodically interrupts your code to see what function you were in at that instant. If the code isn't running very long, it may only collect a small number of data points. In contrast, [`callgrind`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) instruments your code and tracks each function call and return and checks how much time was spent between hooks. This gives it a much fuller view, even if the run is short. This has a downside, it slows the program down quite a bit.

Another advantage of [`callgrind`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) is that you can stop, start, and save its data collection. So if you don't want to monitor your program's startup or want to catch only the time it's doing a particular thing, you can. Plus, there's a tool called [`kcachegrind`](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) that can give you a great graphical view of the data you collected.

If you can tolerate slowing your program down by a factor of four while you're running it for testing, use `callgrind` instead -- it's part of `valgrind`.

If you're using Linux, your distribution probably has a `valgrind` package and a package that includes `kcachegrind` (which may be called [kdesdk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdesdk) or something else). It's worth the time invested to learn how to use them (they are not as easy to get started with as `gprof`). I think you'll find the `kcachegrind`'s GUI impressive (look at this [screenshot](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Shot3Large.html)). And, as its name suggests, it can analyze `cachegrind` output too.

Comment: "interrupts your code to see what function you were in at that instant, what function had called it, and so on" Not quite right. It does see what function the PC is in at that instant. It does not look up the stack at that instant. (If only it did.) What it does is count, each time a function is entered, which function is calling it. From that, it tries to figure everything else out, with [very limited success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981121/how-exactly-does-gprof-work/5046039#5046039).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Rather than complicating my answer, I just removed the incorrect phrase.